# I do not know what is wrong with my function

Tags: python, function, attributes, 3-tier

I have this code. However I am not able to run it as a function.

```
def verify_result_same():
    if verify_result_same.is_identical() & verify_result_same.confidence() > 0.5:
            face_client.face.verify_face_to_face(source_image1_id, detected_faces_ids[0])
            print('Faces from {} & {} are of the same person, with confidence: {}'
            .format(source_image_file_name1, target_image_file_names[0], verify_result_same.confidence))
            print("Valid face verification")

    else: 
            print('Faces from {} & {} are of a different person, with confidence: {}'
            .format(source_image_file_name1, target_image_file_names[0], verify_result_same.confidence))
            print("Invalid face verification")
            text = "Face verification is not valid. Please try again."
            send_msg(text)
```

I am getting errors such as:

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'is_identical'
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'confidence'
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: What are `is_identical` and `confidence`? and why are you trying to call them from `verify_result_same`?

Comment: I don't see why this would work to begin with? Where are these variable declarations, and more importantly, you shouldn't be able to access them from a function, nor meta call the function and access it either.

Comment: What are you checking for *is_identical* and *confidence*, this given function? Please expand your question.

Comment: use `f` strings: `f"some text {some_var}"`

Answer (score 0):

```
if verify_result_same.is_identical() & verify_result_same.is_confident() < 0.5:
```

Here you have used "verify_result_same" object which is same as the function you defined in the previous line.

Answer (score 0):

`verify_result_same` is a function, and you maybe have defined a class named `verify_result_same`. So you should rename your function name from  `verify_result_same` to something others.